# How do I make a artifact stored in Google's Artifact Registry public?

Tags: google-artifact-registry

I currently have a Google NPM Registry using Artifact Registry. I would like to make certain modules public and others private. Is there a way to do this? Is there like a "public" Service account or something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the official documentation on [Configuring public access to a repository](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/access-control#public):

> If you have artifacts that you want to make available to anyone on the internet without authentication, store them in a repository that you make public.

To configure a repository for public read-only access, grant the **Artifact Registry Reader** role to the member `allUsers`.

**[gcloud](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/access-control#gcloud_2):**

```
gcloud artifacts repositories add-iam-policy-binding REPOSITORY \
--location=LOCATION --member=allUsers --role=ROLE
```

**[Console](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/access-control#console_2):**

```
1. Open the Repositories page in the Cloud Console.
2. Select the appropriate repository.
3. On the Permissions tab, click Add Member.
4. In New members field, enter `allUsers`.
5. Select the role Artifact Registry Reader.
6. Set a per-user limit on Artifact Registry API requests to prevent misuse by unauthenticated users.
```

For more information, see this article on [configuring access control in Artifact Registry](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/access-control).

Comment: On a side not you will need to be and Artifact Registry Administrator (Role) to accomplish this.

Comment: Any idea how can I make sure that the repo is never made public.
Or detect which repos are made public. using any automation/cloud run etc?